# eclipse c++ function defined in header could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to compile a c++ program however, I am getting the error

```
Function 'Argument' could not be resolved ...... Semantic Error
```

However `Argument` is defined in `app.h` which I have included in the project.

I have included the header files by going to `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes`. Under `GNU C++` Clicking `Add`, then `File System` and putting in the path to the files.

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

The line giving me an error is:

```
ARGUMENTS = {
  Argument ("input", "input image", "the input image.").type_image_in (),
  Argument ("ouput", "output image", "the output image.").type_image_out (),
  Argument::End
};
```

and in 'app.h':

```
#define ARGUMENTS   const MR::Argument __command_arguments[]
```

SOLUTION:
Closing the project and reopening it solved the problem......

Comment: Now it is a good idea to show your code.

Comment: You should be asking about the **first error** you get.  It looks like solving that error (the one you mention in your now-deleted comment) will also solve the error in your posted question.

Comment: Hi Drew: The first error in the list is "Function 'Argument' could not be resolved." (Line 52) What I began to write, was that in the list of errors, there appears another error "Symbol 'MR' could not be resolved." This error appears later in the list but the line on which the error occurs is Line 41 (so the error should have appeared first)... regardless, namespace MR is also defined in 'app.h' and is not being resolved by eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: Closing the project and reopening it solved the problem......