# Eclipse C.D.T. can't recognize standard functions or "NULL"

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, null

I have been having this problem for weeks and have not been able to find a solution.

When trying to use Eclipse or trying to compile with plain GCC or G++ through a terminal, there are a number of standard functions (plus the "NULL" variable) that are not recognized, including the to_string method.

I have attempted to add many different headers to the program in an attempt to find the correct files, but to no avail. I have tried `#including <string>, <stdio.h>, <stddef.h>, <cstdlib>`, and pretty much any other standard header I could find in forum posts that might contain the to_String function. I even tried all of these #includes with AND without the ".h" extension. Still, not matter what I tried, to_string and NULL were not recognized (among other methods).

I've been through many forums and many forum posts and tried many solutions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065616/multiple-could-not-be-resolved-problems-using-eclipse-with-mingw), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381137/eclipse-function-to-string-could-not-be-resolved), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478415/eclipse-c-function-defined-in-header-could-not-be-resolved-solved), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g), and more. Still, I have found no solution.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Eclipse C.D.T., Eclipse as a whole, GCC, and G++. I have tried adding -std=c++11 and/or -std=c++99 flags to the GCC command or g++ command. I have tried building in Eclipse with Linux GCC, Cross GCC, and other versions of GCC.

I am running Eclipse 3.8 with both J.D.T. and C.D.T. packages installed on 64-bit Linux Mint 16 Petra.

If anyone could help me resolve this issue, "grateful" would not properly express my gratitude toward you.

EDIT:
Here is the output of `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
```

Here's a sample of the code the code that is having errors. Please keep in mind that I have attempted to add other #includes not currently shown and I have reason to believe that a missing #include is not the problem.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Month[13] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

string x;

class Date_Time {
private:
    int minute, hour, day, month, year;
public:

    Date_Time(int minute, int hour, int day, int month, int year) {
        this->minute = minute;
        this->hour = hour;
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;
    }

    string toString() {
        string min = to_string(minute);
        if (min.length() == 1)
            min = '0' + min;

        return to_string(month) + "/" + to_string(day) + "/" + to_string(year)
                + " " + to_string(hour) + ":" + min;

    }

    void addMinutes(int min) {

        minute = min + minute;
        if (minute > 59) {
            minute = minute - 60;
            hour = hour + 1;
        }
        if (hour > 24) {
            hour = hour - 24;
            day = day + 1;
        }

        if (day > Month[month])
            day = day - Month[month];
        month = month + 1;

        if (month > 12) {
            month = 1;
            year = year + 1;

        }
    }

    int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    int getMinutes() {
        return minute;
    }

};
```

EDIT: The summary of the comments below is that we have determined that the cause is that Eclipse is not recognizing C++11 standard functions and keywords. I installed NetBeans on my system with their C/C++ plugin and the exact same errors are occurring. I can't seem to get NetBeans or Eclipse to recognize C++11 features despite adding the `-std=c++11` flag in multiple places in the project configurations.

As of right now, Eclipse can finally compile without giving C++11 errors; however, in the code window, C++11 functions and features are still marked as errors with a red underline, so the issue is still not completely resolved. All I need is for someone to tell me how to get Eclispe and/or NetBeans to recognize C++11 features in its error parsers.

Thanks again in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Can you share the version of your gcc(gcc -v).

Comment: Please include an example source file that can be used to reproduce your problem in your post.

Comment: My version is 4.8.1. I'll edit the original question to show the entire output of `gcc -v` since it's too big to paste in this comment.

Comment: I will also add a sample of the code.

Comment: I added a sample of code and the full output of gcc -v. Also, one of the other methods not recognized in addition to to_string and NULL is strcmp/stricmp.

Comment: If using C++11, code `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: All right. I've done some more searching and researching and testing and I think that the problem is that Eclipse can't recognize c++11 methods and tools, including NULL, nullptr, to_string(), strcmp(), stricmp(), and free(). @leeduhem suggested one way of getting Eclipse to recognize c++11, but it did not work for me. Any one know how to make Eclipse 3.8 recognize and use c++11 libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile your source code with

```
g++ -std=c++11 ...
```

According to [`to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/), it is a C++ 2011 feature.

---

In Eclipse Kepler, you could set this by selecting

Project >> Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Compiler >> Dialect

and choosing `ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x)` for `Language standard`.

And you should choose `[All configurations]` for `Configuration` at `C/C++ Build`.

Comment: I did that before, but I tried it again to make sure. It's hard to say whether or not it worked in the terminal, but Eclispe still calls to_String an error, claiming "Function 'to_string' could not be resolved".

Comment: @REALDrummer What is the `g++` options given by your Eclipse?

Comment: In Project >> Properties >> C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Compiler >> Miscellaneous, I have the flags listed as `-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11`.

Comment: @REALDrummer Try this: Project >> Properties >> C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> GCC C++ Compiler >> Dialect >> Language standard, and choose `ISO C++11`.

Comment: I changed my Configuration to "[All configurations]" and it did not change anything visibly. As for the "Language Standard" setting, it appears Eclipse 3.8 differs from Kepler here. I went to the "GCC C++ Compiler" setting directory you referred to, but I found no "Dialect" or "Language Standard" settings there.

Comment: @REALDrummer Add `-std=c++11` in "Miscellaneous" works in Eclipse 3.8. If you run `Project >> Build Project`, you should be able to see in "Console" the actual `g++` command line options used by Eclipse.

Comment: Okay. @leeduhem Good news and bad news. I've tried adding that `-std=c++11` flag before to no avail, but I checked the command line options that appear in the console during runtime like you suggested. I did get the flag to actually appear there now (I'm not sure why it wasn't before) and the errors saying methods like `to_string()` aren't recognized have disappeared in the compiler. However, the bad news is that Eclipse still marks them as errors in the code window.

Comment: Since Eclipse C.D.T. was having these issues, I tried installing NetBeans with their C/C++ plugin to see if it would work any better. NetBeans had the same errors as Eclipse. I just can't seem to get either of them to recognize C++11 features.

Comment: @REALDrummer Those error marks are made by the static code analyzer, however I do not know how to make them recognize C++11 features.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help thus far. I'm going to probably make a new question to rephrase and reorganize the question based on what you've helped me figure out so far.